# unable to view the whole Live stream video captured in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, live-streaming, aspect-ratio

I'm using react native nodemediaclient to publish live stream video and use MUX server to collect the live video.

Live streaming is working fine however, certain part of the live video feed coming off my camera is cut off and part of the video is shown on my Mux server dashboard.

I'm guessing this could be because of the aspect ratio passed from NodeCameraModule could be different. Any suggestions on how to define an aspect ratio of the live camera feed collected using NodeCameraModule?

Am using the code mentioned below,

```
 <NodeCameraView
              style={styles.videoStream}
              ref={vb => {
                this.vb = vb;
              }}
              outputUrl={
                `rtmp://api/key`
              }
              camera={{cameraId: 1, cameraFrontMirror: true}}
              audio={{bitrate: 32000, profile: 1, samplerate: 44100}}
              video={{
                preset: 12,
                bitrate: 400000,
                profile: 0,
                fps: 15,
                videoFrontMirror: false,
              }}
              autopreview={true}
              smoothSkinLevel = {1}
            />
```

Comment: Hi Ruben, Dylan from Mux here.If I'm understanding this right, you are sending video from NodeCameraView and the video is appearing cropped? I haven't used NodeCameraView (going to try to give it a whirl) Mux shouldn't be cropping anything, we _should_ be maintaining the aspect ratio of the stream that is sent.

Comment: Hi Dylan, I have figured the solution for the issue. It had to do with NodeCameraView settings not Mux. Thanks for the time.

Comment: @dylanjha Im facing a similar issue, are you able to share the setting that you published with?

Comment: @designbuildplay try to change the preset value to 1